# Can I use Different charger: Similar Voltage, lower Amps?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, charger

My computer uses at 19.5V 9.23A charger.

I would like to use a 19V 4.74A charger on the same laptop.

The polarities and connectors are the same.

[This article](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/choose-right-power-adapter-charger-phone-laptop/) is the most comprehensive explanation I've been able to find online, however it doesn't address my particular issue, where the voltage *and* the amperage are lower.  The voltage is only slightly lower, so I'm curious as to if the `Current too Low` section applies to me or if because it's slightly lower does that section not apply to me and so what is the actual possible results of using the charger?

Thanks!

Comment: The voltage and polarity of the new charger must be the same as the old one but the amperage of the new charger can be higher (i.e. can be higher but not lower than the old one).

Comment: The accepted answer in your linked question says the volts/amps must both be the same. The top comment for the accepted answer says the volts must be the same but the amperage for the new charger must be the same or higher. I think if you read the article I link to you'll see that both those 'answers' are (not very accurate) oversimplifications

Comment: There are some inaccuracies in that article.  But to your question, the voltage difference isn't enough to be an issue.  The current difference probably is.  The laptop might not need 9.23A, or might be able to operate with lower using some conservation strategies (see comments on the dupe I linked to).  But you're talking about half the capacity.  You might be able to use it to charge the battery while powered off, and then run on battery.  I wouldn't count on being able to operate from it.

Answer (score 1):

Product: Laptop charger 19.5V 9.23A
Problem: To exchange laptop charger to lower spec, 19.0V 4.74A
Human Curiosity: Possible results of using the lower spec charger to laptop
Laptop: N/A

Most of the technical power supply give the minimum spec to its product. It depend on you brand of laptop. Power supply usage is to charge battery and support voltage to the laptop.

Minimum spec or standard spec provide is 19.5V 9.23A, Meaning higher voltage will damage the component inside especially on IC. Lower voltage will result longer time to charge the battery and it not blow up your components. You cant on your laptop if lower voltage supplied. As long as the voltage provided can operate your laptop, then it is fine to use even though given lower voltage supply.

Your component will malfunction if given lower voltage. Lower voltage cant damage your component it just cant make your laptop to start/on. Higher voltage than specification can damage your component laptop especially capacitor and IC.

We concern about voltage only and damaging your component. Lower voltage is OK as long as laptop can operate.

I hope answered your question

Comment: Your answer focuses on the voltage.  The question is about the radically different current capacity.